# Unable to installed ie 11 in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Somehow my IE11 got replaced with Microsoft edge and I tried many ways to get the IE back, but not succeeded.

I tried resetting internet option setting but its not showing the internet explorer settings at all

I have downloaded the latest browser from official website and when I tried to install it its just says

[image: Restart confirmation]

but when I restart nothing will be done at all, also I checked the IE folder its just empty.

Please help me fix this

Answer (score 3):

IE is dead, and Microsoft will make great efforts to ensure it's not
used any more.

But you don't need to download and install Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10
because it's already installed. You should be able to type
`Internet Explorer` in the Start menu and select it from the list of results.
Or you may directly run `iexplore.exe`.

If you have disabled Internet Explorer, you may re-enable it in
*Settings > Apps > Optional features > Internet Explorer 11*.

To repair Internet Explorer, run `inetcpl.cpl`,
select the Advanced tab and click "Reset" under "Reset Internet Explorer".

It's unknown how long Microsoft will let you continue to use
Internet Explorer before blocking it completely.
It's my best recommendation to get used to Microsoft Edge or its
sibling Chrome.

Note that you can use Microsoft Edge in Internet Explorer compatibility
mode.

You enable it
from the three-dots menu, Settings, Default browser, and set
"Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer Mode", finally
restart Edge.

To use it on an open website, click the three-dots menu, More tools,
and click "Reload in Internet Explorer mode".